# Does a metric tensor imply the existence of a manifold?

Tags: manifolds, riemannian-geometry, general-relativity

If I define a general metric tensor for dimensions $d\geq 2$, does this imply there exists a (pseudo-)Riemannian manifold which admits this metric? I am specifically interested in Lorentzian manifolds, but also in the general case.

EDIT: I am specifically considering the metric tensor $$g_{\mu\nu}=\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 0 \\ 0 & \sinh t\end{bmatrix}$$

using the coordinates $t\in[0,\infty)$ and $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$.

Comment: What do you mean by "define a metric tensor"? The formal mathematical definition of a Riemannian metric is that it is a section of the tensor bundle $T^{0,2}M$ _over a smooth manifold_ that satisfies the conditions of symmetry and positive definiteness. That is, in order to define a metric tensor a manifold is an ingredient that you must input. So in view of the _usual notion of the definition of a metric tensor_, your question makes absolutely no sense. Now, it is entirely possible that you have a different notion in mind of what it means to "define a general metric tensor", but if so you ...

Comment: ... need to [Edit] your question to specify what it is that you have in mind.

Comment: In general relativity you typically write the metric tensor and that gives you a certain manifold. Am I wrong about that?

Comment: Yes, you are very wrong about that.

Comment: If you write down the explicit form of the metric tensor in terms of its line elements relative to some coordinate system, then you are just saying that your underlying manifold is some open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (represented by the coordinate system) and you've defined a metric over that open set. There are also other ways of specifying the metric structure, but they all work under the assumption that you have certain topological data available.

Comment: So I guess a more accurate question would be how do I show a manifold exists which admits a certain metric.

Comment: @WillieWong In physics texts on GR, the author will actually define a spacetime by its metric. For instance, the Schwarzschild spacetime is *defined* by it's metric. One should "properly" say first that it's $\Bbb R^2\times S^2$ with the standard smooth structure, and THEN put on the metric. OP's confusion is understandable.

Comment: Also, physics texts will just "solve" the Einstein equation without specifying the topology or smooth structure of the underlying manifold. And in the solution of the Cauchy problem one does actually construct a manifold such that the metric obeys the Einstein equations. I can't think of any standard GR texts (Wald, Hakwing-Ellis, Carroll, etc.) that actually tell you which manifold Schwarzschild spacetime is supposed to be. EDIT: Straumann states it.

Comment: @0celo7 : what _physicists_ do is their business. They do a lot of mathematically questionable stuff. // In terms of the Cauchy problem, the manifold constructed _always_ has the topological/smooth structure of $\mathbb{R}\times \Sigma$, where $\Sigma$ is the initial given manifold for the space-like data. You can look at Ringstrom's text. Or you can look at [my paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.4833375). // In terms of Schwarzschild, look at O'Neill's text on Semi-Riemannian geometry.

Comment: @0celo7: Also, Wald does in fact say it (page 120, right after defining the radial coordinate). // The point of my comments to the OP is to get him to realize that any description of a "metric tensor" must have an underlying manifold, even if they are not explicitly referred to.

Comment: @WillCunningham: your [updated version](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1946460/does-a-metric-tensor-imply-the-existence-of-a-manifold#comment3996412_1946460) is not really any better. Again, how do you say what a metric is? To say that something admits a certain metric, you have to first give me that metric. But to give me that metric, you necessarily give me a manifold that exhibits that metric by definition.

Comment: The question (and my explanation) can be made clearer if you can edit your question to include an example of what is a "metric" for which you are unsure whether there exists a manifold realizing it.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up the notions of manifold and Riemannian structure. By definition, a metric can only be defined on a manifold, and this metric defines the Riemannian structure. You have things backwards.

In your case, you already have your manifold, in this case a 2-dimensional half-cylinder with its border (note that it is thus not a manifold, but a manifold with border), which is a $\mathcal{C}^\infty$ manifold with its standard topology/atlas.

Then you get to define your "metric" (in your case it is not actually pseudo-Riemannian, as it will be degenerate on the border of your manifold). This gives your manifold the additional metric structure.